Flutter List-detail canonical layout implementation
I am struggling in implementing the List-detail canonical layout showed in M3 specifications. That's the one in the current Gmail design with the list on the left, and the email on the right (or in Whatsapp, with the chat list on the left and selected conversation on the right).
I have now implemented it like that:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'List-detail',
      home: ListDetailScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ListDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListDetailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListDetailScreen> createState() => _ListDetailScreenState();
}

class _ListDetailScreenState extends State<ListDetailScreen> {
  bool largeScreen = false;
  int? selectedIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    largeScreen = width > 600;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (largeScreen) {
      return Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListScreen(
              onSelectedItem: onSelectedItem,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: DetailScreen(
              index: selectedIndex,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      if (selectedIndex == null) {
        return ListScreen(
          onSelectedItem: onSelectedItem,
        );
      } else {
        return DetailScreen(
          index: selectedIndex,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  void onSelectedItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(int) onSelectedItem;

  const ListScreen({super.key, required this.onSelectedItem});

  @override
  State<ListScreen> createState() => _ListScreenState();
}

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('List'),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: List.generate(100, (index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
            onTap: () => widget.onSelectedItem(index),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? index;

  const DetailScreen({super.key, this.index});

  @override
  State<DetailScreen> createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Detail'),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: _buildContent(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    if (widget.index == null) {
      return const Text('Please select an item...');
    }
    return Text('Selected item ${widget.index}');
  }
}

I wanted to know if there's a less naive approach, using Navigators and different screens instead of manipulating the layout like I'm doing.
